# IOCP thread monitoring in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await

I was playing with Async/Await and I/O operations. I wanted to see the IOCP threads in action. But I am not able to monitor them in visual studio (2013) Thread window. I was expecting that 'code written after await' will be executed by IOCP thread. But as per visual studio, either main thread or worker thread executes these statements

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: While *some* APIs in .NET will callback on an IOCP thread, they're actually pretty rare. Usually, the BCL code will transition to a regular thread pool thread before calling back into your code; only the lowest-level APIs will call into your code while still on an IOCP thread.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I would let this opportunity go without saying Thanks to you for your blogs on Asyn/Await. They are really informative and helpful. Coming back to your answer. Do you mean all async call starts their execution on IOCP thread but most of them execute callback on regular Threadpool thread?

Comment: No, I mean that when I/O completes, it (usually) starts on an IOCP thread but it (usually) transfers to a regular threadpool thread at some point before it even completes the `Task`.

Comment: You mean "it (usually) transfer to regular worker thread even before starting callback (while executing await statement)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "executing await statement".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all async IO in the .NET Framework uses IOCP. Sockets do:

```
using (var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
    socket.BeginConnect("google.com", 80, ar =>
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }, null);
    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

The callback runs on an IOCP thread:

[image]

Comment: Thanks usr for the answer! After trying your sample, I tested with FileStream.BeginRead, that also behaves the same and run callback on IOPC. But when I tested ReadAsync, callback was executed on regular thread. Any idea why this behavior is different. Apart from that even with your sample, if you look at the visual studio's Thread window, current thread is shown as regular worker thread and not IOCP.

Comment: Post executable code.; I don't think VS knows about IOCP. They are just normal threads that happen to call GetQueuedCompletionStatus in some way. In practice the distinction is not relevant. Why are you even asking? Curious?

Comment: I am curious because I read somewhere that we should not execute CPU bound code on IO callback as it can lead into IO thread hijacking. That is the reason two different thread pool are maintained. I am not sure though. Nevertheless, your answer helped me so I have accepted it. Thanks again!

Comment: I think you should disregard that advice. APCs are practically irrelevant to .NET code.